# Android SQLite select maximum value that is less than another value

Tags: android, sqlite

Example Schema: Table(Id, Time).

How can I go about selecting the row with the maximum Time that is less than another given Time (i.e. the previous time)?.

I was thinking something along the lines of:

```
SELECT MAX(Time) FROM SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Time < x
```

but I can't remember the proper syntax or if there is another more efficient way.

Comment: `SELECT MAX(Time) FROM Table WHERE Time < x` this will also work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tried and tested. This works

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;

CREATE TABLE DATES(Id integer PRIMARY KEY, Time DATETIME);

INSERT INTO DATES VALUES(1, DATETIME("2015-05-21 10:07:00"));
INSERT INTO DATES VALUES(2, DATETIME("2015-05-21 10:08:00"));
INSERT INTO DATES VALUES(3, DATETIME("2015-05-21 10:10:00"));
INSERT INTO DATES VALUES(4, DATETIME("2015-05-21 10:12:00"));
INSERT INTO DATES VALUES(5, DATETIME("2015-05-21 10:09:00"));
COMMIT;

SELECT * FROM DATES;


SELECT MAX(Time) FROM DATES WHERE Time < DATETIME("2015-05-21 10:09:42");
```

Comment: I am storing Time as an INT in UNIX time, but this would work for that as well. Thanks you!

Answer (score 0):

select MAX(TIME) from TABLE where Time >VALUE;

I assume that you are storing TIME as a number.

Because SQLite does not have a storage class for Time.

If you are using Time function,

select MAX(time(TIME)) from TABLE where time(TIME) > time(VALUE);